# Nested path in #include statement in adobe script is not working

Tags: scripting, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

While writing a plugin for adobe illustrator, I am facing a very weird issue that nested path in #include statement is not working.

```
#include "../folder1/folder2/photoutils.jsx"
```

is not working. While

```
#include "../folder1/photoutils.jsx"
```

is working.

I am struggling to find out the answer for this behaviour.

Comment: How is your folder structure?

Comment: my folder structure is like this "folder1/folder2/photoutils.jsx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot confirm your problem. With the following folder structure the include works fine.

```
.
├── currentfolder
│   └── index.jsx
└── folder1
    └── folder2
        └── include.jsx
```

content of index.jsx

```
#include "../folder1/folder2/include.jsx"
say();
```

content of include.jsx

```
function say() {
  $.writeln('Hello World');
}
```

Tested from ESTK and Illustrator.

Comment: I was messing with the location of folder2 from my currentfolder.  Thanks for your response.